# Resolving blank pages issue with FPDF library

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

The PDF for Avery labels 5160 is created beautifully, but every other page is blank. I have only 7 labels, which are the odd-numbered pages, but I end up with 13 because all the even-numbered pages are blank. I've double-checked the measurements for the margins and the space between the next label.

```
// SESSION Stuff here
} else {
    require_once('inc/pdf_label.php'); // extends FPDF - http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php
    $pdf = new PDF_Label('5160');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
    $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0);
    $pdf->Footer(false);
    $pdf->Header(false);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false); // setting true creates same result of blank pages
    // get DB table info to print labels
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `delivery_format`='Postal' && `membership_expires` >= '" . $ninety_days . "' ORDER BY `name_merge` ASC";
    if(!$result = $xxxx_db->query($sql)) {
        die("There was an error running the query [" . $xxxx_db->error . "]");
    }
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dates = "Expires:" . date('n/j/y', strtotime($row['membership_expires'])) . " Joined:" . date('n/j/y', strtotime($row['signup_date']));
        $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s %s %s",
            $dates,
            $row['name_merge'],
            $row['street'],
            $row['city'],
            $row['state'],
            $row['zip']);
        $pdf->Add_Label($text);
        $y++; // next row
        if($y == 10 ) { // end of page wrap to next column
            $x++;
            $y = 0;
            if($x == 3 ) { // end of page
                $x = 0;
                $y = 0;
                $pdf->AddPage();
            }
        }
    }
    $pdf->Output('my_labels', 'I');
}
```

Comment: Without looking at your code, my first guess is that each page is just to long for one label, so it uses an extra label. Either change the paper dimensions in your OS, but don't make it longer than the labels actually are, or make the pages you try to print shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The handling of `$x` and `$y` is obsolete as this is handled internally by the `PDF_Label` class.

Same for the `AddPage()` call which is the main issue for your problem. Just remove this and it should work.

The souce code of the class can be found [here](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php). You can find the whole handling of rows and cols and also the `AddPage()` call in the `Add_Label()` method.